# How to make a SwiftUI View a property of a Protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

I'm trying to extend a protocol so that a certain few impls of the protocol have a view associated with them.  However, because a SwiftUI View is a protocol, this is proving to be a challenge.

```
import SwiftUI


protocol ParentProtocol {
  var anyProperty: String { get }
}

protocol ChildProtocol : ParentProtocol {
  associatedtype V
  var someView: V { get }
}

class ChildImpl : ChildProtocol {
  var someView : some View {
    Text("Hello World")
  }

  var anyProperty: String = ""

}

class ChildMgr {
  var child: ParentProtocol = ChildImpl()

  func getView() -> some View {
    guard let child = child as? ChildProtocol else { return EmptyView() }
    return child.someView
  }
}
```

Its not clear to me where to constrain the ChildProtocol's associated type to a View (or Text for that matter).

At the `guard let child = ...` I get the following compiler error:
`Protocol 'ChildProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

and when returning the chid's view I get:
`Member 'someView' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'ChildProtocol'; use a generic constraint instead`

I think the answer may be in this thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/7350
but frankly its confusing on how to apply it to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use runtime checks. Use constrained extensions.

I also don't see a reason for you to be using classes.

```swift
protocol ChildProtocol: ParentProtocol {
  associatedtype View: SwiftUI.View
  var someView: View { get }
}

final class ChildImpl: ChildProtocol {
  var someView: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
  }

  var anyProperty: String = ""
}

final class ChildMgr<Child: ParentProtocol> {
  var child: Child

  init(child: Child) {
    self.child = child
  }
}

extension ChildMgr where Child: ChildProtocol {
  func getView() -> some View {
    child.someView
  }
}

extension ChildMgr {
  func getView() -> some View {
    EmptyView()
  }
}

extension ChildMgr where Child == ChildImpl {
  convenience init() {
    self.init(child: .init())
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jessy@ this gets me closer. 

One thing I should have been more explicit about is that the `ChildMgr` may (will) vary what `child` is set to, which can be either and impl of `ParentProtocol` or `ChildProtocol` I think this is ok with that.

However, I have an appServices singleton which creates the `ChildManager` and instantiating needs a concrete type it appears:

```
class AppServices {
   private init() {}
  static var shared: AppServices
  var childMgr: ChildMgr<ParentProtocol> // this doesn't compile.
```

Comment: Protocols do not conform to themselves. It sounds like you're trying to use the Objective-C-style approach of using existentials instead of generics. You should rethink why you're trying to go that route—it will bring pain and bugs!